# python parse page class name select error

Tags: python

write to a python program using beautifulsoup to parse a html page:

```
 soup_content = BeautifulSoup(u_f_page, "html.parser")


 if soup_content.find("li", attrs={"class": "_698"}) == None:
        u_f_name = ""
        u_f_c_unit = ""
 else:
        for u_f_c_li in soup_content.find_all("li",attrs={"class":"_698"}):
            print(u_f_c_li)
```

when I check the result of print(u_f_c_li), I found the all the

```
<li class="_698">
 ...
 ...
</li>
```

has been obtained and print successfully, however, I found other content in this page also obtained and print out, see:

```
<li class="followListItem _1fic _698">
...
...
...
</li>
```

I just need the

```
<li class="_698">...</li>
```

content, I do not need the

```
<li class="followListItem _1fic _698">....</li>
```

content, I suppose there is sth wrong in the sentense:

```
for u_f_c_li in soup_content.find_all("li",attrs={"class":"_698"}):
```

because

```
<li class="followListItem _1fic _698">
```

also include the "_698" in the class name, so its content also be obtained, but I do not need its content, how to just obtain class="_698", not obtain class ="followListItem _1fic _698"

Could you please help me to solve it

Answer (score 1):

This code is a bit messy , but it will give you the desired result .

```
soup_content = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

if soup_content.find("li", attrs={"class": "_698"}) is None :
    u_f_name = ""
    u_f_c_unit = ""
else : 
    li_list = [ li for li in soup_content.find_all("li", {"class":"_698"}) if all(x == '_698' for x in li.get('class')) ]
    for u_f_c_li in li_list :
        print(u_f_c_li)
```

Comment: ok, but if there are other <li class="..."> that contains other class name rathen than followListItem and _1fic, how to deal with it, for example ,there are <li class="fsb fwl  _698">...</li>, I also want to obtain only the content of <li class="_698">...</li>, not the content of  <li class="fsb fwl  _698">...</li>,what should I do, there may many different class names with "_698" in li, I just need obtain <li class="_698">...</li>

Comment: ok，thanks, could you please tell me where you learn these programming technique, I search it online and ask many classmates, but nobody else taught me.Could you tell me where can obtain these technique

Comment: I 'm afraid it's not as simple as reading a book , it takes time and effort .

Comment: If you want to be a good coder , you need to write a lot of code , and study code written by others . As i said , it takes some time , but you 'll get there , i thing you 're on the right path .